# vb.net change row background colour in word table

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in vb.net

```
oDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
```

that adds a row onto a table in word, how can i change the background colour of the row?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do it at the "row" level as you mentioned, you can use the .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor property of each row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845467(v=office.15).aspx

```
    oDoc.Tables(1).Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorLightGreen
    oDoc.Tables(1).Rows(2).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorLightOrange
    oDoc.Tables(1).Rows(3).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorLightYellow
```